# How to terminate or close (quit) an app after opening it? (python)

Tags: python, subprocess

I use the code below to open the an app but what about if I want to close the app.

```py
music = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "open/System/Applications/Music.app"])
```

Comment: `open` itself is a program that can be run with `Popen`: `Popen(["open", "/System/Applications/Music.app"])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use AppleScript:

```
> subprocess.run(["open", "/System/Applications/Music.app"])
> subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", 'tell application "Music" to quit'])
```

Note that unlike Python, AppleScript requires double-quoted strings.

---

Music is running essentially independently of your Python process; I'm not aware of an easy way to get or keep an object that represents the process. In both cases, we are working indirectly.

First, we run `open`, which asks `launchd` to run Music for us. `open` immediately exists, so there's no sense keeping a `Popen` instance representing it on hand.

When we are done with Music, we use `osascript` to run a very short AppleScript, which simply asks the Music application to quit itself. Like `open`, `osascript` exits immediately, and Music does what we ask it to, which is exit.